# Upload image from gallery and display in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display an image uploaded from the gallery in an AlertDialog but it's not working for me right now.

My code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent imageGetter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        activityLauncher.launch(imageGetter);
    }

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        Uri selectedImage = result.getData().getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};//Array size of 1, and we put in a string
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String user_image_path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        myImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        Picasso.get().load(user_image_path).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).
                        setMessage("Message above the image").
                        setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss()).
                        setView(myImageView);
        builder.create().show();
        cursor.close();
    });
```

The gallery opens up and I can choose a picture but after I choose a picture it goes back and a blank dialog with no image (the message is there) shows up.

I tried adding "file:/// " to the Picasso but that doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Picasso.get().load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);` and get rid of all the `MediaStore` stuff. You might also consider using a `DialogFragment` rather than `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Comment: @shiho remove one `/` from the file and try again. Like this `file://`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Uri directly to display the picture?
Just like:

```
Uri selectedImage = result.getData().getData();
Picasso.get().load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);
```

At the same time, it is worth noting that

> resolver.query()

is a I/O operation. It is not recommended to operate directly on the main thread

Comment: hi, image still doesn't show up tho

Comment: Try put image into a layout file, like:
`View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_in_this_layout, null)`
Than call `alertDialog.setView(view)`